# How do I get file names from a directory in a repository using Github API

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

I'm trying to make an electron app that gets the file names of a directory in a repository. I just don't know how to do this with the api. I know there is a way, I just don't know how.

**For example:**

I want to get the file names in the src/ directory of a github repository using the api.

I use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make api requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Get repository content endpoint, documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content)

Check out an example using [Octokit](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#repos-get-content)

| List Repository contents | [<kbd>View in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70935023) |
| --- | --- |

```js
// If you don't send the path property, by default will send the contents from the root level
const repoContent = await github.rest.repos.getContent({
  owner: 'repo-owner',
  repo: 'repo-name'
});
  
console.log('Files found at root level', repoContent.data.map((file) => file.name));
```